# How do you include FreeRTOS header files in different source files in an Espressif IDF Eclipse project

Tags: c, eclipse, esp32, freertos

Upon creating an ESPRESSIF project in Eclipse, I see the following includes already exists in `main`.

```
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/event_groups.h"
#include "esp_syst"
#include "esp_wifi.h"
#include "esp_event.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "lwip/sockets.h"
```

I guess the included files are referenced by the path defined in `IDF_PATH`. But how do you go about using these files in any other source file? The same include won't work.

```
// file1.c
#include "lwip/sockets.h" // Unresolved inclusion: "lwip/sockets.h"
```

Below is the snapshot of the properties. I don't see a `C/C++ build` section for some reason otherwise I know there's an option to put the file paths in there which could then just be used by any source file without specifying the relative path.
[image]

For reference: I followed this tutorial -> https://github.com/espressif/idf-eclipse-plugin/blob/master/README.md#create-a-new-project until `Compiling the Project`

Comment: Why won’t the same include work? What happens when you try it?

Comment: so I try to include the same file in `file1.c`, it won't recognize the path. Is the path consistent across the project though? I don't think so

Comment: Please post a minimal example of the code you tried and the actual, complete error message you got.

Comment: Edited the description

Comment: Post more, for a [example], please.

Comment: there's nothing that's code related though. It's just the includes.

Comment: I'm not sure why C/C++ Build option isn't there for you, possibly make sure that CDT plugins are fully installed in your Eclipse. The option to add directory includes is there under C/C++ Build -> Settings -> C Compiler / C++ Compiler -> Includes.

Comment: Can you try creating an Espressif IDF project on your end and see if C/C++ build option appears for you?

Comment: Looks like the reference path is already defined in Espressif project, hence why I didn't have to include the entire relative path in the `main` and it works. Just not sure how come I can't include other project source files in `main` and not being able to include esp32 specific files in other source files which are included in `main`